# datetime not matching with epoch timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have below code where I am getting current datetime in utc and then converting it to epoch.

```
ct = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
f = ct.replace(microsecond=0)   # removing the microseconds from ct
print("Current time: {}".format(f))
epoch = f.timestamp()
print("Epoch time: {}".format(epoch))
```

Below is the output

```
Current time: 2022-05-24 14:57:12
Epoch time: 1653400632.0
```

In above output, current time in UTC is correct. But its epoch time seems wrong, because if I [convert](https://currentmillis.com/) epoch time (`1653400632000`) to datetime, it comes out to be `Tue May 24 2022 13:57:12`. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how can we convert a datetime to epoch time.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-datetime-to-epoch/

Comment: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html